# Python Palindrom program using Stacks

Tags: python, stack, palindrome

My assignment was to come up with a palindrome program in python. Which I did here

```
def isPalindrome(word):
    for i in range(len(word)//2):
        if word[i] != word[-1-i]:
            return False
    return True

print (isPalindrome("maam")) #returns TRUE
print (isPalindrome("madam")) #returns TRUE
print (isPalindrome("hello")) #returns FALSE
print (isPalindrome("macdam")) #returns FALSE
print (isPalindrome("buffalolaffub")) #returns TRUE
print (isPalindrome("argentina")) #returns FALSE
```

Now my instructor wants this to be converted using `Stack`s. Can anybody help with this?

Here's the `Stack` data structure I have:

```
class Stack:

    def __init__(self):
        self.items = []

    def isEmpty(self):
        return self.items == []

    def push(self, item):
        self.items.append(item)

    def pop(self):
        return self.items.pop()

    def peek(self):
        return self.items[len(self.items)-1]

    def size(self):
        return len(self.items)
```

Answer (score 2):

Given:

```
tests=["maam", "madam","hello","macdam","buffalolaffub","argentina"]
```

Idiomatic Python check for a string being a palindrome would be something like this:

```
word==word[::-1]   # True or False
```

So you can print a list of palindromes like this:

```
print [word for word in tests if word==word[::-1]]
```

To do this with a stack, you need to turn the string into a list and then the Python list / stack operations are available to you. Here is a small demo:

```
def stack_cmp(s1,s2):
    l1=list(s1)
    l2=list(s2)
    if len(l1)!=len(l2): return False
    while True:
        try:
            if l1.pop()!=l2.pop(): return False
        except IndexError:
            return True  

print [word for word in tests if stack_cmp(word, word[::-1])]
```

An alternate version of `stack_cmp` that does not use exceptions:

```
def stack_cmp(s1,s2):
    l1=list(s1)
    l2=list(s2)
    while l1 and l2:
        if l1.pop()!=l2.pop(): return False
    if l1 or l2: return False
    return True
```

Which then works this wway:

```
>>> stack_cmp('mmmm','mmmm')
True
>>> stack_cmp('mmmm','mmmmm')
False
```

Your teacher may object to the use of slices to reverse a list; ie, `revered_list=orig_list[::-1]`. If that is the case, you can use this:

```
reversed_list=[]
orig_list_copy=orig_list[:]
while orig_list_copy:
    reversed_list.append(orig_list_copy.pop())    # this reverses the list
```

This works as a Stack class with a palidrome checker:

```
class Stack(object):
    def __init__(self,items):
        self.items=[]
        for e in items:
            self.push(e)

    def push(self,item):
        self.items.append(item)

    def pop(self):
        return self.items.pop()

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.items)  

    def isPalindrome(self):
        tr=Stack([])
        t=Stack(self.items)
        while t.items:
            tr.push(t.pop())
        t=Stack(self.items)    
        while t.items and tr.items:
            c1=t.pop()
            c2=tr.pop()
            print c1,c2
            if c1!=c2: return False
        return True
```

Comment: @the_wolf the line below gives me an invalid syntax error





`print [word for word in tests if stack_cmp(word, word[::-1])]`

Comment: @the_wolf If i take that line out, my print results are not correct unless in the tests i write the test word & then the test word backwards. Heres the code...

`from stackDS import Stack  `  


`def isPalindrome(word1, word2):

        l1=list(word1)
        l2=list(word2)
        if len(l1)!=len(l2): return False
        while True:
            try:
                if l1.pop()!=l2.pop(): return False
            except IndexError:
                return True ` 

`print (isPalindrome("maam", "maam")) #Expected Output: TRUE
print (isPalindrome("hello", "olleh")) #Expected Output: FALSE`

Comment: This fails to answer the problem.  It is not using the stack class to detect palindromes.

Answer (score 0):

Well since a stack is First In Last Out they naturally reverse things.  You could iterate over the string, pushing for the first half then popping and comparing for the last half.

Comment: i am just struggling with getting it started.. I am not familiar with python language at all @cmd

Comment: @user2052503 in that case I would run through the tutorial http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/index.html. Its fairly quick and of great help getting started.